AWS ALB load shedding
I can’t figure out what mechanism in the ALB is limiting the load. Increasing the capacity (in this case, ECS containers) doesn’t help; if the load is reduced to 50,000 requests, there are no fluctuations. What could be causing this behavior? What are the possible solutions to the problem?
[Target response time]
[Requests]
I tried changing the load balancing types and increasing the container capacity.
